# I am getting MultiValueDictKeyError at /gf/ 'name'

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lSUl.png)I am getting following error. I have no option to set name property(before same error pop up but resolved by changing name) since I am using form then how to resolve it.
MultiValueDictKeyError at /gf/

```
'name'
Request Method:GETRequest URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/gf/?age=28&csrfmiddlewaretoken=0NribXMzevzOMqH3YoYiK65wqODRNRj3oiKBT50X5NK4BTi7j87UhMTRndTpz8S5Django Version:4.2Exception Type:MultiValueDictKeyErrorException Value:'name'
```

Code:
views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import *
def name_view(request):
    form=Nameform()
    return render(request,'name.html',{'form':form})
def age_view(request):
    form=AgeForm()
    name=request.GET['name']
    request.session['name']=name
    return render(request,'age.html',{'form':form})
def gf_view(request):
    form=GFForm()
    age=request.GET['age']
    request.session['age']=age
    return render(request,'gf.html',{'form':form})
def result_view(request):
    gf=request.GET['gf']
    request.session['gf']=gf
    return render(request,'result.html')
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
class Nameform(forms.Form):
    name=forms.CharField()
class AgeForm(forms.Form):
    age=forms.IntegerField()
class GFForm(forms.Form):
    gf=forms.CharField()
```

name.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr"> 
     <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8"> 
         <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Name Registration Form</h1><hr>
        <form action="{%url 'age'%}" > 
            {{form}}
            {%csrf_token%}<br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit Name">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

age.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr"> 
     <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8"> 
         <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Age Registration Form</h1><hr>
        <form action="{%url 'gf'%}" > 
            {{form}}
            {%csrf_token%}<br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit Age">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

gf.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr"> 
     <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8"> 
         <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>GF Registration Form</h1><hr>
        <form action="{%url 'result'%}" > 
            {{form}}
            {%csrf_token%}<br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit GF's Name">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

result.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr"> 
     <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8"> 
         <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {%if request.session%}
            <h1>Thanks for providing information..Plz confirm once</h1>
            <ul>
            {% for key,value in request.session.items %}
            <li><h2>{{key|upper}}:{{value:title}}</h2></li>
            {%end for%}
            </ul>
        {%else%}
            <p> No information available</p>
            {%endif%}
    </body>
</html>
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('name/',views.name_view,name='name'),
    path('age/',views.age_view,name='age'),
    path('gf/',views.age_view,name='gf'),
    path('result/',views.result_view,name='result')
]
```

The same problem occurred previously but it gets resolved by changing the name property of the input, this time I am using forms.py to use the inbuilt form functionality inside the html pages which doesn't allow me to do the change property. I don't know either that, is that error?
after doing some debug its like when I click on submit on name.html the name value retrieved and stored in name of age_view()fucntion. and when I click on submit of age.html then name value written as None so thats the two values comming for same cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you put the wrong view in gf path (age_view)

```
urlpatterns = [
path('name/',views.name_view,name='name'),
    path('age/',views.age_view,name='age'),
    path('gf/',views.age_view,name='gf'),
    path('result/',views.result_view,name='result')
]
```